# Screen remains black after suspending

Tags: arch-linux, display, suspend, laptop

Suspend used to work just fine on my laptop but since a recent update I am encountering an issue. After I wake the laptop from suspend, the screen doesn't come on. Everything else *seems* to turn on just fine, but no image on the screen. The laptop is fully awake, but there is just no image on the screen. However, there is one "fix" that I have found. If I have woken the laptop, and I am facing the black screen, I can use an HDMI cable to wake it up. What I have to do is plug an HDMI cable in (one that is connected to a TV, for instance), and just the act of plugging it in will "wake up" the screen. It is very odd but it works. Problem, of course, is that I can't carry a tv around wherever I go so this is not a permanent solution.

Here is some more debugging code.

Typical journal entries when waking up from suspend:

```
Apr 19 18:55:08 george kernel: PM: Syncing filesystems ... done.
Apr 19 18:55:08 george kernel: Freezing user space processes ... (elapsed 0.001 seconds) done.
Apr 19 18:55:08 george kernel: OOM killer disabled.
Apr 19 18:55:08 george kernel: Freezing remaining freezable tasks ... (elapsed 0.001 seconds) done.
Apr 19 18:55:08 george kernel: Suspending console(s) (use no_console_suspend to debug)
Apr 19 18:55:08 george kernel: wlp1s0: deauthenticating from 51:b7:bf:0a:bc:63 by local choice (Reason: 3=DEAUTH_LEAVING)
Apr 19 18:55:08 george kernel: sd 0:0:0:0: [sda] Synchronizing SCSI cache
Apr 19 18:55:08 george kernel: sd 0:0:0:0: [sda] Stopping disk
Apr 19 18:55:08 george kernel: wlp1s0: failed to remove key (1, ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff) from hardware (-22)
Apr 19 18:55:08 george kernel: ACPI: Preparing to enter system sleep state S3
Apr 19 18:55:08 george kernel: ACPI: EC: event blocked
Apr 19 18:55:08 george kernel: ACPI: EC: EC stopped
Apr 19 18:55:08 george kernel: PM: Saving platform NVS memory
Apr 19 18:55:08 george kernel: Disabling non-boot CPUs ...
Apr 19 18:55:08 george kernel: smpboot: CPU 1 is now offline
Apr 19 18:55:08 george kernel: ACPI: Low-level resume complete
Apr 19 18:55:08 george kernel: ACPI: EC: EC started
Apr 19 18:55:08 george kernel: PM: Restoring platform NVS memory
Apr 19 18:55:08 george kernel: Enabling non-boot CPUs ...
Apr 19 18:55:08 george kernel: x86: Booting SMP configuration:
Apr 19 18:55:08 george kernel: smpboot: Booting Node 0 Processor 1 APIC 0x2
Apr 19 18:55:08 george kernel:  cache: parent cpu1 should not be sleeping
Apr 19 18:55:08 george kernel: CPU1 is up
Apr 19 18:55:08 george kernel: ACPI: Waking up from system sleep state S3
Apr 19 18:55:08 george kernel: ACPI: EC: event unblocked
Apr 19 18:55:08 george kernel: [drm:intel_display_resume [i915]] *ERROR* Restoring old state failed with -22
Apr 19 18:55:08 george kernel: sd 0:0:0:0: [sda] Starting disk
Apr 19 18:55:08 george kernel: usb 1-7: reset high-speed USB device number 5 using xhci_hcd
Apr 19 18:55:08 george kernel: ata1: SATA link up 6.0 Gbps (SStatus 133 SControl 300)
Apr 19 18:55:08 george kernel: ata1.00: configured for UDMA/133
Apr 19 18:55:08 george kernel: usb 1-3: reset high-speed USB device number 2 using xhci_hcd
Apr 19 18:55:08 george kernel: OOM killer enabled.
Apr 19 18:55:08 george systemd-logind[266]: Lid opened.
Apr 19 18:55:08 george dhcpcd[14830]: wlp1s0: carrier lost
Apr 19 18:55:08 george kernel: Restarting tasks ... done.
Apr 19 18:55:08 george kernel: PM: suspend exit
Apr 19 18:55:08 george systemd-sleep[25353]: System resumed.
Apr 19 18:55:08 george systemd[1]: Started Suspend.
Apr 19 18:55:08 george systemd[1]: sleep.target: Unit not needed anymore. Stopping.
Apr 19 18:55:08 george systemd[1]: Stopped target Sleep.
Apr 19 18:55:08 george systemd[1]: Reached target Suspend.
Apr 19 18:55:08 george systemd[1]: suspend.target: Unit not needed anymore. Stopping.
Apr 19 18:55:08 george systemd[1]: Stopped target Suspend.
Apr 19 18:55:08 george systemd-logind[266]: Operation 'sleep' finished.
Apr 19 18:55:08 george wicd[271]: sending signal ALRM to pid 14830
Apr 19 18:55:08 george wicd[271]: waiting for pid 14830 to exit
Apr 19 18:55:08 george dhcpcd[25410]: sending signal ALRM to pid 14830
Apr 19 18:55:08 george dhcpcd[25410]: waiting for pid 14830 to exit
Apr 19 18:55:08 george dhcpcd[14830]: wlp1s0: deleting route to 192.168.178.0/24
Apr 19 18:55:08 george dhcpcd[14830]: wlp1s0: deleting default route via 192.168.178.1
Apr 19 18:55:08 george dhcpcd[14830]: received SIGALRM, releasing
Apr 19 18:55:08 george dhcpcd[14830]: wlp1s0: removing interface
Apr 19 18:55:08 george dhcpcd[14830]: dhcpcd exited
Apr 19 18:55:08 george kernel: IPv6: ADDRCONF(NETDEV_UP): wlp1s0: link is not ready
```

And here VGA card details:

```
$ lspci -vnn | grep VGA -A 12
00:02.0 VGA compatible controller [0300]: Intel Corporation HD Graphics [8086:1606] (rev 08) (prog-if 00 [VGA controller])
    Subsystem: Intel Corporation HD Graphics [8086:1606]
    Flags: bus master, fast devsel, latency 0, IRQ 46
    Memory at e0000000 (64-bit, non-prefetchable) [size=16M]
    Memory at d0000000 (64-bit, prefetchable) [size=256M]
    I/O ports at 1800 [size=64]
    [virtual] Expansion ROM at 000c0000 [disabled] [size=128K]
    Capabilities: [90] MSI: Enable+ Count=1/1 Maskable- 64bit-
    Capabilities: [d0] Power Management version 2
    Capabilities: [a4] PCI Advanced Features
    Kernel driver in use: i915
    Kernel modules: i915
```

I used the latest kernel before but changed it to LTS after this problem arose:

```
$ uname -a Linux george 4.14.34-1-lts #1 SMP Thu Apr 12 20:30:09 CEST 2018 x86_64 GNU/Linux
```

Is there anyone who has an idea what this can be?

I am using i3 as a window manager, no desktop environment, and Arch Linux operating system.

Comment: Have you found a solution?

Comment: Not really. I carried an HDMI cable with me so that whenever it happened, I could connect to a TV if one was available to revive the screen. It has been incredibly frustrating. However, in the past couple of weeks the problem has been resolved. At least, that's what seems to be the case! So whatever was causing this is hopefully fixed in one of the kernel (or other) updates.

Comment: By any chance, did you notice what exactly could solve your issue? Maybe you can identify, what was changed to solve it? I'm asking because I have very similar issue :) https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/497793/30230 which I cannot solve as of yet :(

Comment: Unfortunately I am not sure what did the trick. I _did_ upgrade my kernel, and stopped using LTS. I now have 4.20.6-arch1-1-ARCH. That is the only thing I can think of. Good luck -- do post an update if you ultimately find out what caused this!

Comment: Looks like I made it! My failing kernel was for some reason lacking `CONFIG_DRM_FBDEV_EMULATION=y`

Comment: OK great to hear! Thanks for posting this, it may help others.